# Why use the Random Class of Java when you can Use the SecureRandom Class?

Tags: java, random, cryptography

As I understand it, there are two main classes of Java that are able to perform pseudorandom activites: the `Random` class and the `SecureRandom` class. Both generate pseudorandom numbers. However, the `SecureRandom` class generates cryptographically-secure numbers.

Why even use the `Random` class when you can use the `SecureRandom` class, which generates more unpredictable numbers? Many programmers (especially video game programmers) use solely the `Random` class, but both of the classes have almost the same core method (both can generate a pseudorandom integer). Both classes can also be seeded with a long value.

My only explanation is that the `Random` class operates faster than the `SecureRandom` class. Is this true? If not, then why do many Java programmers prefer the `Random` class than the `SecureRandom` class?

Comment: [To start with](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html): *"[...] Depending on the implementation, the generateSeed and nextBytes methods **may block** as entropy is being gathered [...]"*. Also, `Random` provides a deterministic random sequence and is presumably faster in most implementations.

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of likely reasons

- Random is older so there is more examples.
- Random is random enough for many cases and much faster.
- Random produces the same result on all platforms, and always the same results for a seed (The default SecureRandom can be different if you don't also specify the strategy)

Comment: Also, in some testing situations, you want to repeat the same series of random numbers.  You can do that with `Random` by giving it the same seed.  You cannot do that with `SecureRandom`.

Comment: @rossum it is possible with some SecureRandom strategies, but can't rely on the default strategy to do this.